# mysql want to get data for a specific month and date

Tags: mysql

```
a_id employee_id    date       checkin          checkout
1       1        31-10-2012   09:13:54 AM      05:30:55 PM
2       1        01-11-2012   09:34:39 AM      05:30:55 PM
```

i have the following attendence table....i want to get all checkin and check out time for a specific month for eg 01-10-2012 to 31-10-2012....i have used something like this

```
select `employee_id`,`date`,`checkin`,`checkout`
from `attendence` 
where `date` >= '01-10-2012'
    and `date` < '31-10-2012'
```

now the problem with this query is retuns me the result but with the first date of the next month

**this is the result which it gives me**

```
 employee_id    date       checkin          checkout
     1        31-10-2012   09:13:54 AM      05:30:55 PM
     1        01-11-2012   09:34:39 AM      05:30:55 PM
```

**i wanted the result only for a specific month  something like this with the above query**

```
employee_id         date       checkin          checkout
         1        31-10-2012   09:13:54 AM      05:30:55 PM



a_id    int(11) No       
employee_id int(11) No       
date    varchar(15) No       
checkin varchar(32) No       
checkout    varchar(32) No
```

plzzzz help guys im stuck here :(

Comment: Can you describe your table structure?

Comment: you have a wrong table structure, `datatype` for `date` should be a `date` instead of `varchar(15)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select `employee_id`,`date`,`checkin`,`checkout`
from `attendence` 
where DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y") = "10-2012"
```

View [`FiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54eb1/1/0) It works for me

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
select `employee_id`,`date`,`checkin`,`checkout`
from `attendence` 
where `date` BETWEEN  MONTH('01-10-2012')
AND  MONTH( '31-10-2012')
```

if want with year and month

```
select `employee_id`,`date`,`checkin`,`checkout`
from `attendence` 
where `date` BETWEEN  MONTH('01-10-2012')
AND  MONTH( '31-10-2012')
AND `date` BETWEEN  YEAR('01-10-2012')
AND  YEAR( '31-10-2012')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `datetime` type for `date` column to native date comparsion.

OR

Try this:

```
select `employee_id`,`date`,`checkin`,`checkout`
from `attendence` 
where DATE(`date`) >= DATE('01-10-2012')
    and DATE(`date`) < DATE('31-10-2012')
```

Comment: i changed it to datetime but its still returning empty set

Answer (score 0):

Notice the format of the string inside DATE. It should be yyyy-MM-dd.

```
select 
    `employee_id`,`date`,`checkin`,`checkout` 
from 
    `attendence` 
where 
DATE(`date`) >= DATE('2012-10-01') 
    and DATE(`date`) < DATE('2012-10-31');
```